# Sed overwrites match groups from line beginning in OSX

Tags: regex, macos, sed, terminal, line-breaks

In OSX, sed behaves as below:

```
echo -en 'xxx abc\r\nxxx aa bb cc\r\n' | sed -E 's/xxx (.*)/\1->/g'
->c
-> bb cc
```

While I was expecting the following:

```
echo -en 'xxx abc\r\nxxx aa bb cc\r\n' | sed -E 's/xxx (.*)/\1->/g'
abc->
aa bb cc->
```

I am simply matching a line using `xxx` then putting everything else somewhere in a string that I constructed. It seems it is related to `\r`, but am not quite sure how to fix it, without first trimming down `\r` from the text file first. (The example above does not mention any text file, but you can imagine the output of `echo` was in a text file).

Any explanation why `->` overwrites the group match?

Comment: do you want to necessarily retain `\r`? try `sed -E 's/\r//; s/xxx (.*)/\1->/g; s/$/\r/'`

Comment: Files in OSX has those, but of course I do not need `\r`, though dumping them will make those files look bad in OSX. Also, in your solution, `->` eats away characters as well.

Comment: I checked it on `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2` and it gives your expected output...

Comment: can you also try `sed -E 's/xxx (.*)\r/\1->\r/'` ? (note: `g` flag is not needed)

Comment: As I said, I am talking about OSX. It is BSD sed, not GNU.

Comment: yeah, but I don't have a way to verify.. that's why I am giving you based on my version and asking if it works for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the [carriage-return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) (`\r`) chars.

Tested on OS X:

```
[STEP 107] $ printf 'xxx abc\r\nxxx aa bb cc\r\n' | sed -E 's/xxx (.*)/\1->/g'
->c
-> bb cc
[STEP 108] $ printf 'xxx abc\r\nxxx aa bb cc\r\n' | sed -E 's/xxx (.*)/\1->/g' \
             | hexdump -C
00000000  61 62 63 0d 2d 3e 0a 61  61 20 62 62 20 63 63 0d  |abc.->.aa bb cc.|
00000010  2d 3e 0a                                          |->.|
[STEP 109] $ printf 'xxx abc\nxxx aa bb cc\n' | sed -E 's/xxx (.*)/\1->/g'
abc->
aa bb cc->
[STEP 110] $ printf 'abc\r->\n'
->c
[STEP 111] $
```

Take `printf 'abc\r->\n'` for example: It would first print `abc`, then `\r` would move the cursor back to the beginning of the line, then print `->` which would overwrite `ab`, so finally we see `->c`.

Comment: YES! I did figure out it had to do with matching and printing `\r`, which is present in OSX. But I never knew that `\r\n` actually represents "flush to the beginning, then proceed to next line". Thanks!